# Is there a way to find out if a particular Wine software is installed and a general way to run the software?

Tags: wine

Let's suppose [my script](https://github.com/burianvlastimil/lightshot-print-screen-linux-handler/blob/master/lightshot_print_screen) expects [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/wine-lightshot.html) screenshot software to be installed into [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Is there a way to query [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (some people use [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) as a front-end for it)?

If it is possible, is there a general way to run the software?

---

On my laptop the desktop entry has a terribly complicated launch line:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/vlastimil/.lightshot" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/vlastimil/.lightshot/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Lightshot/Lightshot.lnk
```

Therefore I think it might not be that simple.

Comment: There is no "tool" on `wine` that could emulate the Control Panel behavior as you are asking, where you can list all installed software. Also, you are using a custom `WINEPREFIX` so, there is no way `wine` can guess what prefixes you have setup on your machine, and that why prefixes exist: To better isolate windows software specific configuration and needs+dependencies it may have.

Comment: @nwildner I was afraid of that. Pity, thank you, good to know.

Comment: I'm curious now. Why do you use "lightshot" if there are alternatives on Linux that could do exactly what this software does? Screenshots of a specific cropped/rectangle area

Comment: @nwildner Because it has an online library, where I can manage what I uploaded. It is really handy.

Comment: Fair enough :). Really good tool. Sometimes, you have to `wine` since there arent good enough alternatives

Comment: Hey @vlastimil, i saw this new tool calles Flameshot and remembered this discussion about wine and lightshot. it could be worth it trying - https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot - It takes screenshots, makes edits on the fly and has some integration with imgur to upload files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "tool" on `wine` that could emulate this Control Panel behavior as you are asking, where you can list all installed software, and `winecfg` will only configure things specific of the last `WINEPREFIX` being used, but will not list software installed on it. Also, you are using a custom `WINEPREFIX` so, there is no way wine can guess what prefixes you have setup on your machine.

Why prefixes exist? To better isolate windows software specific configuration and needs+dependencies it may have.

Some library management tools like [Lutris](https://lutris.net/) can handle per-app prefixes and wine versions, but you will have to install your software using it, or creating a new entry on Lutris manually, pretty much the same way is done with PlayOnLinux.

Comment: I hadn’t thought of the list of software that shows up in the Windows Control Panel; but that list is available in Wine, using `wine uninstaller`. Your point about prefixes still holds obviously, and that’s the main blocker here.